# Sharing common header and footer CCLayers across multiple CCScenes and make it updatable

Tags: layout, cocos2d-iphone, nsnotifications, cclayer

In my cocos2d game I am needing to share a common header and footer that will appear on every game layer.

The header contains things like cash, and sprites -- whereas the footer contains CCMenuItem buttons to move between the different game scenes.

The header/footer appear on a Z-index slightly higher than the current scene/layer so that it appears on top of everything being displayed.

The header could, for example, look like this:

> Cash: $5,000

The footer could, for example look like a CCMenu with sprite buttons, like this:

> Home | Marketplace

This would be considered a hud system.

Now, I've tried adding the HUD to every scene in a fashion similar to this;

```
HudLayer *hud = [HudLayer node]
[self addChild:hud z:1];
```

But, it causes an assertion error.

> *** Assertion failure in -[CCMenuItemSprite addChild:z:tag:] ...

This is caused because the HUD cannot be added again in different scenes.  This is a real frustration I have with cocos2d.

The only way I've been able to solve this problem up to now is to have a `BaseScene` which has a `HUD` as a CCLayer and I load all subsequent CCLayers using NSNotifications.

Code now follows;

```
#define HudBase 1
#define kHUDTag 9000

#import "cocos2d.h"

@interface BaseScene : CCScene

@end

@class HeaderHUDLayer;
@interface BaseLayer : CCLayer
{
    CCNode *currentNode;
    CCLayer *thisLayer;
    HeaderHUDLayer *hud;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) CCNode *currentNode;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CCLayer *thisLayer;
@property (nonatomic, retain) HeaderHUDLayer *hud;

-(void) changeNodeTo:(CCNode *)thisNode;
-(void) changeHUDSceneObserver:(NSNotification *)notification;

@end

@implementation BaseScene

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self addChild:[BaseLayer node] z:0 tag:800];
    }
    return self;
}
@end

@implementation BaseLayer
@synthesize currentNode, thisLayer;
@synthesize hud;

-(id) init
{
    if ((self =[super init]))
    {
        NSLog(@"HUD Scene");

        self.hud = [HeaderHUDLayer node];

        if (self.currentNode == nil)
        {
            self.currentNode = [MyDashboardScene node];
            [self changeNodeTo:self.currentNode];
        }

        [self addChild:self.hud z:TopZLayer];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector: @selector(changeHUDSceneObserver:) name: @"changeHUDScene" object: nil];
    } // end if
    return self;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [super dealloc];
}


-(void) changeNodeTo:(CCNode *)thisNode
{
    NSLog(@"changeNodeTo");
    [self removeChild:self.currentNode cleanup:YES];
    [self addChild:thisNode z:0];
    self.currentNode = thisNode;
}

-(void) changeHUDSceneObserver:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSLog(@"changeHUDSceneObserver = %@", notification.name);

    if ([notification.name isEqualToString:@"changeHUDScene"]==YES) {
        if ([notification object]!=nil) {
            [self changeNodeTo:[notification object]];
        }
    }
}

@end
```

The header itself is very complex, but in simple terms I have a CCLabel, like this:

```
NSString *txtCash = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cash: %d", [player.cash intValue]];
            self.lblCash = [CCLabelBMFont labelWithString:txtCash fntFile:@"font_minipixi_16.fnt"];
            [lblCash setTag:kCashLabelTag];
            [lblCash setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(1, 0)];
            [lblCash setPosition:CGPointMake(100, 8)];
[self addChild:lblCash];
```

This works great, I can move between all the different parts of the game and the header/footer is common across all scenes.

However, using NSNotifications to change the node causes me real headaches, namely I cannot seem to change the labels (lblCash) inside the HUD and I do not know how to solve this.

For example, if I click on a CCMenuItem which reduce's my cash, the HUD label never updates.

To get around this problem I use another NSNotification to solve this.  Except there are times when I need to have multiple NSNotifications (to change the header, refresh the page or whatever) and I end up with assertion errors because I cannot re-send things.

There are times when I have a NSNotification to update the header, then another NSNotification straight afterward which redirects the node to another node I want to present; again this causes an assertion error.

I feel that the whole thing is descending into a mess of NSNotifications all over the place and makes me very frustrated with cosos2d.

I have tried:

> Making the base scene remove the HUD (and all her children) and re-add
>   it.  This causes an assertion error and does not seem possible to do. 
>   I'm probably coding it wrong though

Trying to cast the BaseScene/Layer and grab the HUD using a tag and updating the label that way.

ie,

```
    BaseLayer *baseLayer = (BaseLayer *) [self.parent getChildByTag:800];
    [baseLayer.hud updateCashAmount];
```

Does not do anything. (The base layers/scenes and hud layer all have a tag).

Neither does,

```
    HeaderHUDLayer *hud = (HeaderHUDLayer *)[base getChildByTag:kHUDTag];
    [hud updateCashAmount];
```

I think the reason why I cannot do the casting is because the NSNotifications have changed the context.

This whole thing has made me very frustrated with cosos2d.

All I want is a common header/footer in lots of scenes, I want to be able to update the header's labels without too much fuss.

Given this, how do I share a common header/footer CCLayer and make the elements inside the header/footer updatable?

Is there a simpler way to do this without having a boatload of NSNotifications all over the place?

With Thanks.

Comment: Over the last few hours I've been working on this, and the way I've been able to get it work so far is to use NSNotifications as per usual, but consolidate all the updates to headers inside one method and then make all the labels a class attribute (ie: `self.someLabel`).  This seems to be working so far.

Comment: You have the same post here http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/32542 and seems that you fixed the problem...i'm confused

Comment: In the URL you've cited I solved the problem of having a HUD on multiple layer, but then I couldn't update anything in the HUD.  In addition, I was told that rather than having a HUD layer and the actual layer in a "base" scene, I should put the HUD in every scene; this caused me a problem in that I could not re-add the HUD because it was already added.  To solve that problem I ended back where I started, that is; using NSNotifications to handle the management of scenes/layers -- but it did not solve how to update labels or elements inside the HUD.

Comment: I also wanted to raise the theory of the best practice on how to specifically create multiple layers using the same assets over and over again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have another solution to this problem.

To recap,

I want to have or share a common header/footer across multiple scenes/layers.

The way I was doing it was to use as BaseScene (CCScene) with a single child which was my HD, and then I used a NSNotification observer to change the underlying child (CCLayer).

This got very messy and things like the HUD overlapped any modal dialogs.

I can't solve the modal dialog problem just yet, but in terms of sharing a common header/footer, I think I may have a solution.

In the book, "Learn cocos2d game development with iOS5" by Steffen Itterheim at around Chapter 5, it talks about using a "semi-singleton"

What follows is a quote;

```
static MultiLayerScene* multiLayerSceneInstance;
+(MultiLayerScene*) sharedLayer {
NSAssert(multiLayerSceneInstance != nil, @"MultiLayerScene not available!");
return multiLayerSceneInstance; }

-(void) dealloc {
// MultiLayerScene will be deallocated now, you must set it to nil multiLayerSceneInstance = nil;
// don't forget to call "super dealloc"
[super dealloc]; }
```

> Simply put, the multiLayerSceneInstance is a static global variable
>   that will hold the current MultiLayerScene object during its lifetime.
>   The static keyword denotes that the multiLayerSceneInstance variable
>   is accessible only within the implementation file it is defined in. At
>   the same time, it is not an instance variable; it lives outside the
>   scope of any class. That’s why it is defined outside any method, and
>   it can be accessed in class methods like sharedLayer.

Access to the GameLayer and UserInterfaceLayer is granted through property getter methods, for ease of use.

This makes it easy to access the various layers from any node of the MultiLayerScene.

In the open source game, [CastleHassle](https://github.com/bryceredd/CastleHassle) the author uses a similar technique which I have been able to look at and "replicate" in a way where I can move from scene to scene (they are actually CCLayers) and share the same common header without those annoying "... child already added" errors.

I am investigating it a bit further, but CastleHassle helped me a lot with this problem and if I experiment with the book's code I may have a further solution.

In summary, the way I've done it is to use the instance concept as per CastleHassle; but I will look at how the book as done it with its concept of a shared instance.

Answer (score 1):

In a project with a common menu layer I use this method to transfer the layer from one scene to another (in Kobold2D this method is already available):

```
-(void) transferToNode:(CCNode*)targetNode
{
    NSAssert(self.parent != nil, @"self hasn't been added as child. Use addChild in this case, transferToNode is only for reassigning child nodes to another node");
    CCNode* selfNode = [self retain];
    [self removeFromParentAndCleanup:NO];
    [targetNode addChild:selfNode z:selfNode.zOrder tag:selfNode.tag];
    [selfNode release];
}
```

It works like this:

```
CCScene* newScene = [MyNewScene node];
[menuLayer transferToNode:newScene];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:newScene];
```

Now the menu layer lives on in the next scene. That's it.

PS: if you use ARC, omit the retain & release lines.

Comment: This looks pretty good. But what is menuLayer?  Is that a CCLayer?

Comment: Lets say you run the game for the very first time, there would be no node to transfer; so it needs to be added.  My question is where does it get added?   As I understand it you are transferring the MenuLayer from one scene to another; but the MenuLayer itself needs to be added somewhere first before it can be used and I'm not sure how you're doing that

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have resolved the problem.

The way I solved this was:

1. Use NSNotifications to move between scenes/layers so that cocos2d does not complain of nodes or other assets already being added.
2. In a NSNotification observer I update headers, or other items on the HUD
   layer I need to update.
3. Use a singelton userData (dictionary) which is shared across the game and so I can pass data to/from the header via the NSNotification.

It is pretty much a hack, but I think it seems to work fine now.

For example, in my HUD scene/layer I create a NSNotification

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector: @selector(changeHUDObserver:) name:@"hudStatus" object:nil];
```

I also create an observer

```
-(void) changeHUDObserver:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSLog(@"changeHUD.status = %@", notification.name);
```

// Grab the data from the state singleton
// There are other ways to do this, but this is just an example
Player *player = [state.userData objectForKey:@"player"];

```
// Update header cash label
    // Cash formatter
    NSLocale *usLocale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"] autorelease];
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setLocale:usLocale];
    [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    [formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:0];
    NSString *txtCash = [formatter stringFromNumber:player.cash];
    [formatter release];

    // Cash Label
    self.lblCash.string = txtCash;
} // end method
```

This is just an example, but I can now send and update stuff in the header.

Although my answer is a hack, I feel that @LearnCocos2d has an answer which should be looked into as a possible alternative.

Thanks

Comment: Whilst this does work, its causing me an unforseen issue -- all modal alerts appear underneath the HUD.  I'm going to play with @LearnCocos2d's answer.  Maybe that'll solve it